# How can I remove the Flutter status bar from a home screen shortcut?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't remove this statusbar from my app, I use it as a webapp and add it to my iphone home screen, does anyone know how to remove it?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wnQ1.png)

```
Future<void> main() async {
  //await Motion.instance.initialize();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //await Geocoding.instance.init(); // Use Geocoding here
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive, overlays: []);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Pantry',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'campton',
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        platform: TargetPlatform.android,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder(
        // Check if user is logged in on Firebase
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().first,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
                child:
                    CircularProgressIndicator()); // Show a loader while checking login state
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              // User is logged in, show your MenuPages
              print("logged");
              return MenuPages();
            } else {
              // User is not logged in
              print("Not logged");
              return LoginPage();
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried changing the colors in index.html but nothing different

Answer (score 0):

[`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setEnabledSystemUIOverlays.html) should do what you want.

You can bring it back with `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values)`.

Import it using

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

---

Update answer (from Flutter 2.5 or latest):

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack);
```

Or you can use another options like:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [
  SystemUiOverlay.bottom
]);  // to only hide the status bar
```

Then when you need to re-show it (like when dispose) use this:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);  // to re-show bars

  }
```

I hope I helped you